# Intellij IDEA cant resolve symbol on string character

Tags: string, intellij-idea, createquery

I have an strange problem with `Intellij IDEA 14 ultimate`

Here my `createQuery()` argument is in `String` , but IDE take error for it:

[image]

The `from Book where isbn= :isbn` line is in `" "`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IntelliJ complains here because it can't find this table and row in datasources.
You need to open your tab called `Datasources`

[image]

and add there your database. Then intelliJ will resolve names and this will be not highlighted as red.

[image]

Other alternative will be disable SQL language injection into string:

[image]

Comment: Check your plugins list. There should be plugin called `Database Tools and SQL`. is it enabled?